# Critiques of blog posts: on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, reviews

Can I use this site to get reviews on the posts I put on my blog to improve my writing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: This is out of date; critiques have since been re-examined and are no longer on-topic. More here: https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/a/879/26

---

Yes, per the [faq](https://writers.stackexchange.com/faq):

> Writing critique questions are also welcome here, provided you provide details and context for your writing, as well as some direction on what type of feedback you're looking for.

Just make sure you provide context and specific questions.

Comment: Thank you Jeff. I was inspired by your post on how to write without writing in coding horror.