# What should we do with this older blog critique question?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I just came across this question:

**[Quality of my blog writing](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/1549/quality-of-my-blog-writing)**

Is this just an old question that would have gotten closed for being too general of a critique, or is this [specific enough](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/a/201/26)?

Answer (score 3):

Close close close.

our critique guidelines have changed over time. This was probably when we were showing more latitude. If it's already floated back up, now's a good time to close it.

Comment: Despite my general openist/includist attitude, I have to concede, "gauge my writing quality, and perhaps provide pointers over where I can improve" is not specific enough.